# Is upgrading to Utopic worth it? Will I encounter lots of bugs?

Tags: gnome, upgrade, laptop, touchscreen, tablet

I have a newer, touchscreen laptop/tablet (a 2-in-1? but it doesn't come apart, it folds back and becomes a tablet), and I'd like the fullest support possible for my newer device. When trying to upgrade by computer to Ubuntu Gnome 14.10 from 14.04 recently, I noticed that the release notes state that Utopic is a devolopment release, not intended for use on production machines. However, I've yet to see a way to install either gnome 3.14, or 3.16 on 14.04. However, I can update the Gnome DE to version 3.14 on Utopic. I was wondering if anyone on here could please tell me, exacly how buggy Utopic is. With a name like Utopic Unicorn, one would think that the software is fully mature. Will I likely encounter a lot of bugs? Is it worth updating past the LTS release to get support for my newer device?

Answer (score 1):

14.10 Utopic has been released (in October last year) and is stable, but is newer than 14.04 LTS Trusty (which could be 'more stable') - 15.04 Vivid is in development and will be released in April. See more [here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases)

As for GNOME, Ubuntu sort of misses out on newer versions due to the timing of GNOME's release and Ubuntu's. So if you want to install a newer version (e.g. 3.14 on Utopic), you need to use [PPA's](https://askubuntu.com/q/4983/178596) to update to it:

```
 sudo apt-add-repository ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3
 sudo apt-add-repository ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3-staging
 sudo apt-add-repository ppa:ricotz/testing
 sudo apt-get update
 sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Note this is experimental, and may break other desktop environments including Unity. [Source](http://techhamlet.com/2014/10/install-gnome-13-14-in-ubuntu/).

(I will add that Fedora and Arch, different distributions of Linux, often have the newer versions of GNOME more easily available by default)

Comment: Yeah, I thought so, but I read that after 14.04, the rest of the 6-month releases would be buggy and experimental, until the next LTS release. Maybe they changed their minds?

Comment: Also, the release notes, when I used the update-manager -d command, said that it was a development release